# Keep streaming audio continuable in background mode

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

Our project is to play streaming live audio (HTTP live streaming) with AVPlayerItem + AVPlayer.

But I encounter two problems:

1. The system enters into sleep mode, after 30 minutes, the system will
   disconnect wifi automatically, so the audio is paused. How do I 
   prevent disconnecting wifi automatically by the system?.
2. After our app enters background mode, sometimes the audio is paused because
   the m3u8 playlist has no change in a little seconds, then the app
   is transfered from background state to suspended state by system.
   How do I fix this?

Settings on our project:

- Add "audio" on "UIBackgroundModes" in project plist file.
- Setting AudioSession category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback

playlist(m3u8): http://dload.kandian.com:22111/945622950.m3u8

Answer (score 0):

This might fix your problems :

1. For the first problem set the `Application uses WiFi` property in the plist file (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12
2. For the second issue you might try calling this before starting the media play :

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
   ```

Hope this helps.

Cheers